# Textfield listener on Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

hi i am trying to use a textfield that upon value changes, i want it to execute a function that filters out a list of items based on the text inputted?

It does not seem to do anything.

I tried adding the searchFilter function call inside `onValueChanges` but upon clicking on the textfield to try and type something, the keyboard doesnt pop up at all

```
  val textState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }

                   TextField(
                        value = textState.value,
                        onValueChange = {
                            textState.value = it
                            viewModel.searchCharacter(textState.value.text)
                        }
                    )
```

If i remove the `viewModel.searchCharacter(textState.value.text`) and add it outside the Textfield, i can now enter something in the actual textfield but it never invokes the searchCharacter function.

My search character method is just a list that apply a filter to

```
fun searchCharacter(name: String) {
    characterList.value?.let {
        characterList.value?.let { characterList ->
            characterList.filter {
                it.name.contains(name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your code should prevent the keyboard from popping up. Have you tried running the app again? I've had issues with compose TextFields not reliably opening the keyboard.

Your `searchCharacter` function doesn't make sense.

- Why is there a redundant `let` block?
- `filter` doesn't modify a list but returns a new one. (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html)

Here's a better way:

```
fun searchCharacter(name: String) {
  characterList.value.filter { it.name.contains(name) }?.let { filtered ->
    characterList.value = filtered
  }
}
```